# How to list down the list of file if contains certain word but exclude if contain other word using glob python?

Tags: python, filepath, glob

I would like to list down the file which contains certain word, but need to exclude it if it contains another specific name

my file is as below:

```
C:\\Users\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Batch_123.xlsx    ---- file 1
C:\\Users\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Batch_456.xlsx    ---- file 2
C:\\Users\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Batch_Red_1.xlsx  ---- file 3
C:\\Users\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Batch_Red_2.xlsx  ---- file 4
C:\\Users\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Batch_Yellow_1.xlsx ---- file 5
C:\\Users\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Batch_Yellow_2.xlsx  ---- file 6
```

and I would like to have the file name: `Batch_123.xlsx and Batch_456.xlsx` only exclude those with `*_1.xlsx, *_2.xlsx, *_3.xlsx, *_4.xlsx, and so on`

I have tried use:
`glob.glob(path + "**/Batch_*[!_1].xlsx", recursive=True)` but it only returns to file 1,2,4,6

Is there any way to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this kind of approach?

```
set(glob.glob(path+"**/Batch_*.xlsx", recursive=True)) - set(glob.glob(path+"**/Batch_*_*.xlsx", recursive=True))
```

I know there probably are better ways but this is easy and clear for the beginner